# How to create a central parameter, like Report-Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create one location on sql server where I store the report-date and all queries and procedures should relate to this one value.
In that way I only have to change the report date on one location and it is valid for all related queries and procedures.

I started with a scalar function that retrieves a value from a table, but this slows down the queries enomoursly.

I tried an inline table valued function, but have no idea how to include this into a query. 

I tried with a table that contains the report-date and used a cross join.
But it says:

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Maybe some of you have an idea what to do here?

Comment: I usually have a table called GeneralParams for stuff like that. Sometimes it has a column per param, sometimes it's an [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: And how do you join this table?

Comment: If it's a colum-per-param then it only has one row, so you can use cross join. If it's an EAV, then use the name to join.

Comment: Good idea. I can use the name to join. It appears in the Select. But I cannot use it to define it in an ON-Clause of another join (here to limit records until report-date)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to create a table, let's say `TblReportDate` with two columns: `id` and `reportDate`.

Then add one row with id `1` like following:

```
+----+------------+
| id | reportDate |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 04.04.2018 |
+----+------------+
```

Now join the table with a `LEFT JOIN` and use the `>=` operator to compare with the `id`-column of the main-table:

```
SELECT * FROM mainTable
LEFT JOIN TblReportDate ON mainTable.id >= TblReportDate.id
```